# takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given or missing 1 required positional argument: 'radius' depending on how I write the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far.

```
# This program uses a value returning function named circle
# that takes the radius of a circle and returns the area and the
# circumference of the circle.

#####################################
# Start program
# Main()
# Get user input of radius from user. 
# Pass argument radius to circle function
# circle()
# Calculate circumference
# Calculate area
# Return values from circle to main
# Main()
# Print circumference 
# Print area
# End program
#####################################

# First we must import the math functions
import math

# Start of program
def main():
    # Get circle's radius from user
    radius=float(input('Enter the radius of the circle: '))

    #Calling the circle funcion while passing radius to it
    circle(radius)

    #Gathering returned results from circle function
    circumference, area = circle()

    #Printing results
    print('Circle circumference is ', circumference)
    print('Circle area is ', area)

# Circle function
def circle(radius):

    # Returning results to main 
    return 2 * math.pi * radius, math.pi * radius**2

# End program
main()
```

But I get this error:

> Enter the radius of the circle: 2 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/shawnclark/Documents/ Introduction to Computer
>   Programming/Chapter 05/Assignment/5.1.py", line 45, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/shawnclark/Documents/ Introduction to Computer Programming/Chapter 05/Assignment/5.1.py", line 32, in main
>       circumference, area = circle() TypeError: circle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'radius'

Comment: Please read the error message carefully, it explains the cause very clearly.

Comment: You're not supposed to make separate calls to `circle` to pass the arguments in and to get the return value. Those are supposed to happen in the same call.

Comment: You're calling `circle` twice. Look carefully at both calls.

Comment: Thanks guys. This section has had me banging my head against the wall for a minute. This problem messed me up because I had to pass in, return and catch the numbers in order to get what the professor wanted. I finally got to the right answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

**Problem 1: Syntax**

As your error message clearly states you are calling the circle() function without passing any argument; however you defined the circle() function as taking one argument.

**Problem 2: Misunderstanding how return values work**

You called circle passing it a radius, however you ignored the return value. Later you try to utilize the return values of circle() without passing it a radius. You should remove the first call to circle() and modify the second call to include the radius argument.

`circumference, area = circle(radius)`

Answer (score 0):

Got there:

> ## Start of program def main():
>
> ```
> # Get circle's radius from user
> radius=int(input('Enter the radius of the circle: '))
> # Catching 
> circumference, area = circle(radius)
> # Print result
> print('Circle circumference is ',circumference)
> print('Circle area is ',area)
> ```
>
> ## Circle function  def circle(rad):
>
> ```
> # Calculate circumference
> circumference = rad * 2 * math.pi
> # Calculate area
> area=rad ** 2 * math.pi
> # Return values
> return circumference, area
> ```
>
> ## End program main()

Thanks for helping a noob.